# How create dynamically new 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array

As in the subject how create new 2D array in C++?
This code below does not work quite well.

```
int** t = new *int[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       t[i] = new int[5];
```

Comment: That's really close, but [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is preferred.

Comment: What do mean with "does not work quite well"? And why not use `std::vector` inside another `std::vector`?

Comment: this question has been asked so many times.  use vector... blah blah.  i wish so would automatically detect potential duplicates and asks for confirmation (if there are potential dups) before every question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `*` in the wrong spot.  Try:

```
int **t = new int *[3];
```

Comment: +1 and I wish I could up-vote it again for fixing *the problem* rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: In production quality C++ code, I'd use a robust **RAII** container like `std::vector` instead of _raw_ C-like arrays allocated with `new[]`, unless there is a strong reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Would `vector< vector< int > >` work?

Comment: Java would work even better but unfortunatelly can't use it ; )

Comment: Just curious why can't you use vector from std? It's a part of any C++ version.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to "flatten" the 2D matrix into a 1D array, storing its elements in a convenient container like `std::vector` (this is more efficient than having a `vector<vector<T>>`). Then you can map the 2D `(row, column)` matrix index into the 1D array index.

If you store the elements in the matrix row-wise, you can use a formula like this:

> ```
> 1D array index = column + row * columns count
> ```

You can wrap that in a convenient C++ class (overloading `operator()` for proper matrix element access):

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public: 
    Matrix(size_t rows, size_t columns)
        : m_data(rows * columns), m_rows(rows), m_columns(columns) {}

    size_t Rows() const { return m_rows; }

    size_t Columns() const { return m_columns; }

    const T & operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const { 
        return m_data[VectorIndex(row, column)];
    }

    T & operator()(size_t row, size_t column) {
        return m_data[VectorIndex(row, column)];
    }

private:
    vector<T> m_data;
    size_t m_rows;    
    size_t m_columns; 

    size_t VectorIndex(size_t row, size_t column) const {
        if (row >= m_rows)
            throw out_of_range("Matrix<T> - Row index out of bound.");
        if (column >= m_columns)
            throw out_of_range("Matrix<T> - Column index out of bound.");           
        return column + row*m_columns;
    }
};
```